# How can I relayout my window to show the softinput keyboard?

Tags: android, android-edittext, window-soft-input-mode

I know there's `statexxx` and `adjustxxx` but neither is my desired behavior.

Suppose I have a `ListView` (match_parent x match_parent) and a `EditText` (match_parent * wrap_content) which sits at the bottom of screen. When the soft keyboard appears , I only want to position the `EditText` somewhere to show the entire input panel while leave the `ListView` as-is.

That is I want the effect same as in WeChat

How can I do that ?

Comment: Isn't WeChat using Custom Keyboard?

Comment: android:imeOption="flagNoFullscreen" check this if it works

Comment: @PsyDuck， no, it's using 3rd party IMEs.

Comment: @Anjali,  it doesn't work

Comment: The background will stay intact if you use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"` and the EditText you want to adjust shows up in some devices by default and in some it does't and it's due to the keyboard variations in devices. You can try implementing 3rd party IME for that, like you suggested.